# Highchart Drill Down do not work for different chart types on same page

Tags: highcharts

I have a scenario where I have to use Rangechart and Column Chart in a single page and I need to call Highchart JS files asynchronously for both Chart type.

Rangechart works fine and drill down also works fine, but drill down for Column Chart does not work.

**Error**: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'stacks')"

**jsfiddle URL**: http://jsfiddle.net/qk3en5a8/

**Complete Code** (Although available on demo side but giving here for quick reference)

<div id="container" style="=width: 210px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<div id="container1" style="=width: 210px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

```
(async () => {
        const { default: Highcharts } =
            await import('https://code.highcharts.com/es-modules/masters/highcharts.src.js');
        await import('https://code.highcharts.com/es-modules/masters/highcharts-more.src.js');
        await import('https://code.highcharts.com/es-modules/masters/modules/drilldown.src.js');

        Highcharts.chart('container', {
            chart: {
                type: 'columnrange',
                inverted: false
            },
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: '7'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'category',
                labels: {
                    rotation: 0,
                    y: -110,
                    style: {
                        color: '#111',
                        fontSize: '.85rem',
                    }
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                plotLines: [{
                    color: '#ffff',
                    width: 30,
                    value: 0,
                    zIndex: 5
                }]
            },
            plotOptions: {
                columnrange: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        format: '{y}'
                    }
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: true,
                align: 'left'
            }, credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            exporting: {
                enabled: false
            },



            series: [{
                data: [{
                    low: -34,
                    high: 39,
                    drilldown: 'marketrisk1'
                }, {
                    low: -36,
                    high: 36,
                    drilldown: 'creditqualityrisk1'
                }, {
                    low: -33,
                    high: 40,
                    drilldown: 'liquidityrisk1'
                }, {
                    low: -15,
                    high: 57,
                    drilldown: 'inflationrisk1'
                }]
            }, {
                data: [{
                    low: -32,
                    high: 40,
                    drilldown: 'marketrisk2'
                }, {
                    low: -34,
                    high: 30,
                    drilldown: 'creditqualityrisk2'
                }, {
                    low: -26,
                    high: 49,
                    drilldown: 'liquidityrisk2'
                }, {
                    low: -12,
                    high: 61,
                    drilldown: 'inflationrisk2'
                }]
            }, {
                name: 'Public pension',
                data: [{
                    low: -41,
                    high: 28,
                    drilldown: 'marketrisk3'
                }, {
                    low: -30,
                    high: 35,
                    drilldown: 'creditqualityrisk3'
                }, {
                    low: -32,
                    high: 36,
                    drilldown: 'liquidityrisk3'
                }, {
                    low: -10,
                    high: 63,
                    drilldown: 'inflationrisk3'
                }]
            }],
            drilldown: {
                breadcrumbs: {
                    buttonTheme: {
                        fill: '#ffffff',
                        padding: 8,
                        stroke: '#253746',
                        'stroke-width': 1,
                        borderRadius: 0,
                        width: 110
                    },
                    floating: true,
                    position: {
                        align: 'right'
                    },
                    showFullPath: false,
                    format: '&#8249; Back to Segments',
                    borderRadius: 0
                },
                series: [{
                    id: 'marketrisk1',
                    showInLegend: false,
                    data: [{
                        low: -24,
                        high: 46
                    }, {
                        low: -40,
                        high: 39
                    }, {
                        low: -31,
                        high: 28
                    }]
                }, {
                    id: 'creditqualityrisk1',
                    showInLegend: false,
                    data: [{
                        low: -22,
                        high: 41
                    }, {
                        low: -38,
                        high: 40
                    }, {
                       low: -44,
                        high: 21
                    }]
                }, {
                    id: 'liquidityrisk1',
                    showInLegend: false,
                    data: [{
                        low: -24,
                        high: 51
                    }, {
                        low: -35,
                        high: 36
                    }, {
                        low: -36,
                        high: 38
                    }]
                }, {
                    id: 'inflationrisk1',
                    showInLegend: false,
                    data: [{
                        low: -12,
                        high: 49
                    }, {
                       low: -16,
                        high: 62
                    }, {
                        low: -15,
                        high: 54
                    }]
                }, {
                    id: 'marketrisk2',
                    showInLegend: false,
                    data: [{
                        low: -43,
                        high: 32
                    }, {
                        low: -25,
                        high: 45
                    }, {
                        low: -33,
                        high: 42
                    }]
                }, {
                    id: 'creditqualityrisk2',
                    showInLegend: false,
                    data: [{
                        low: -39,
                        high: 29
                    }, {
                        low: -34,
                        high: 33
                    }, {
                        low: -26,
                        high: 23
                    }]
                }, {
                    id: 'liquidityrisk2',
                    showInLegend: false,
                    data: [{
                        low: -23,
                        high: 55
                    }, {
                        low: -30,
                        high: 42
                    }, {
                        low: -19,
                        high: 58
                    }]
                }, {
                    id: 'inflationrisk2',
                    showInLegend: false,
                    data: [{
                        low: -10,
                        high: 71
                    }, {
                        low: -11,
                        high: 54
                    }, {
                        low: -19,
                        high: 65
                    }]
                }, {
                    id: 'marketrisk3',
                    showInLegend: false,
                    data: [{
                        low: -33,
                        high: 26
                    }, {
                        low: -43,
                        high: 30
                    }, {
                        low: -48,
                        high: 29
                    }]
                }, {
                    id: 'creditqualityrisk3',
                    showInLegend: false,
                    data: [{
                        low: -23,
                        high: 36
                    }, {
                        low: -33,
                        high: 35
                    }, {
                        low: -39,
                        high: 32
                    }]
                }, {
                    id: 'liquidityrisk3',
                    showInLegend: false,
                    data: [{
                        low: -30,
                        high: 39
                    }, {
                        low: -31,
                        high: 35
                    }, {
                        low: -39,
                        high: 39
                    }]
                }, {
                    id: 'inflationrisk3',
                    showInLegend: false,
                    data: [{
                        low: -20,
                        high: 58
                    }, {
                        low: -18,
                        high: 59
                    }, {
                        low: 0,
                        high: 84
                    }]
                }]
            }



        });
        $('#container').removeAttr('style');
    })();



(async () => {
                      const { default: Highcharts } =
                          await import('https://code.highcharts.com/es-modules/masters/highcharts.src.js');
                      await import('https://code.highcharts.com/es-modules/masters/modules/drilldown.src.js');

                      Highcharts.chart('container1', {
                          chart: {
                              type: 'column',
                              events: {
                                  drilldown: function (e) {
                                      this.setTitle({ text: "after drill down>" });
                                  },
                                  drillup: function (e) {
                                      this.setTitle({ text: 'title' });
                                  }
                              }
                          },
                          title: {
                              align: 'left',
                              text: 'title'
                          },
                          accessibility: {
                              announceNewData: {
                                  enabled: true
                              }
                          },
                          xAxis: {
                              type: 'category'
                          },
                          yAxis: [{
                              className: 'highcharts-color-0',
                              title: {
                                  text: '', enabled: false
                              },
                              labels: {
                                  text: '',
                                  format: '{value}%',
                                  enabled: false
                              }
                          }, {
                              className: 'highcharts-color-1',
                              opposite: true,
                              title: {
                                  text: ''
                              },
                              labels: {
                                  text: ''
                              }
                          }],

                          plotOptions: {
                              series: {
                                  borderWidth: 0,
                                  dataLabels: {
                                      enabled: true,
                                      format: '{point.y}%',
                                      y: 25,
                                      color: 'black'
                                  }
                              }
                          },
                          exporting: {
                              enabled: false
                          },
                          legend: {
                              align: 'left',
                              symbolHeight: 18,
                              symbolWidth: 18,
                              symbolRadius: 12,
                              symbolPadding: 10
                          },
                          tooltip: {
                              formatter: function () {
                                  return this.key + '<br />' + this.series.name +
                                      ':' + this.y + '%'
                              }
                          },
                          series:
                              [{
                                  color: "#c3d642",
                                  data: [
                                      {
                                          y: 43,
                                          drilldown: "yes_all"
                                      },
                                      {
                                          y: 40,
                                          drilldown: "yes_noram"
                                      },
                                      {
                                          y: 46,
                                          drilldown: "yes_emea"
                                      },
                                      {
                                          y: 42,
                                          drilldown: "yes_apac"
                                      }
                                  ]
                              },
                              {
                                  color: "#08bed5",
                                  data: [
                                      {
                                          y: 36,
                                          drilldown: "not_all"
                                      },
                                      {
                                          y: 33,
                                          drilldown: "not_noram"
                                      },
                                      {
                                          y: 34,
                                          drilldown: "not_emea"
                                      },
                                      {
                                          y: 46,
                                          drilldown: "not_apac"
                                      }
                                  ]
                              },
                              {
                                  color: "#ff5048",
                                  data: [
                                      {
                                          y: 19,
                                          drilldown: "no_all"
                                      },
                                      {
                                          y: 26,
                                          drilldown: "no_noram"
                                      },
                                      {
                                          y: 19,
                                          drilldown: "no_emea"
                                      },
                                      {
                                          y: 8,
                                          drilldown: "no_apac"
                                      }
                                  ]
                              }],
                          drilldown: {
                              breadcrumbs: {
                                  buttonTheme: {
                                      fill: '#ffffff',
                                      padding: 8,
                                      stroke: '#253746',
                                      'stroke-width': 1,
                                      borderRadius: 0,
                                      width: 110
                                  },
                                  floating: true,
                                  position: {
                                      align: 'right'
                                  },
                                  showFullPath: false,
                                  format: '&#8249; Back to Region',
                                  borderRadius: 0
                              },
                              series: [{
                                  id: 'yes_all',
                                  showInLegend: false,
                                  data: [
                                      ['a', 51],
                                      ['b', 32],
                                      ['c', 43]
                                  ]
                              }, {
                                  id: 'yes_noram',
                                  showInLegend: false,
                                  data: [
                                      ['a', 54],
                                      ['b', 28],
                                      ['c', 38]
                                  ]
                              }, {
                                  id: 'yes_emea',
                                  showInLegend: false,
                                  data: [
                                      ['a', 57],
                                      ['b', 34],
                                      ['c', 48]
                                  ]
                              }, {
                                  id: 'yes_apac',
                                  showInLegend: false,
                                  data: [
                                      ['a', 31],
                                      ['b', 33],
                                      ['c', 39]
                                  ]
                              }, {
                                  id: 'not_all',
                                  showInLegend: false,
                                  data: [
                                      ['a', 40],
                                      ['b', 44],
                                      ['c', 31]
                                  ]
                              }, {
                                  id: 'not_noram',
                                  showInLegend: false,
                                  data: [
                                      ['a', 41],
                                      ['b', 45],
                                      ['c', 21]
                                  ]
                              }, {
                                  id: 'not_emea',
                                  showInLegend: false,
                                  data: [
                                      ['a', 29],
                                      ['b', 41],
                                      ['c', 34]
                                  ]
                              }, {
                                  id: 'not_apac',
                                  showInLegend: false,
                                  data: [
                                      ['a', 64],
                                      ['b', 51],
                                      ['c', 45]
                                  ]
                              }, {
                                  id: 'no_all',
                                  showInLegend: false,
                                  data: [
                                      ['a', 9],
                                      ['bn', 21],
                                      ['c', 24]
                                  ]
                              }, {
                                  id: 'no_noram',
                                  showInLegend: false,
                                  data: [
                                      ['a', 5],
                                      ['b', 25],
                                      ['c', 41]
                                  ]
                              }, {
                                  id: 'no_emea',
                                  showInLegend: false,
                                  data: [
                                      ['a', 12],
                                      ['b', 21],
                                      ['c', 18]
                                  ]
                              }, {
                                  id: 'no_apac',
                                  showInLegend: false,
                                  data: [
                                      ['a', 5],
                                      ['b', 16],
                                      ['c', 3]
                                  ]
                              }]
                          }, credits: {
                              enabled: true
                          }
                      });
                      $('#container1').removeAttr('style');
                  })();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should be able to import Highcharts and its modules only once, even if you need to show two charts on a single page. So something like below will be enough:

```
(async () => {
    const {
        default: Highcharts
    } =
    await import('https://code.highcharts.com/es-modules/masters/highcharts.src.js');
    await import('https://code.highcharts.com/es-modules/masters/highcharts-more.src.js');
    await import('https://code.highcharts.com/es-modules/masters/modules/drilldown.src.js');

    Highcharts.chart('container', {
        ...
    });
    $('#container').removeAttr('style');

    Highcharts.chart('container1', {
        ...
    });
    $('#container1').removeAttr('style');
})();
```

**Live example:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5w9d1bxs/

---

However, there is a problem with the order of loaded modules in your example. You can check the order here: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/m1px6c5q/

Drilldown will be working correctly if you also import `highcharts-more` in the second async function -

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/v4f395q8/

or if you delay the second importing -

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fk61qw3n/